# Como asignar una imagen a un ImageView mediante una url dinamica

Tags: java, android-studio, api, listview

Estoy haciendo una lista de banderas y sus nombres, pero obtengo los datos de una api, la parte de la imagen trae la ruta, ejemplo "mexico.png" pero no se como traerla del servidor y ponerla en un ImageView.

```
    ImageView imagen = view.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
    String img;
    img = tarjetaL.get(position).getImagen();
    imagen.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(img));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cargar imagen desde una URL en un `ImageView`, puedes realizarlo usando dos bibliotecas, la forma de realizarlo es muy similar:

---

1)[**Glide**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide):

Agrega las siguientes dependencias a tu archivo `build.gradle`:

```
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2'
```

y ahora cargas la url en tu `ImageView` de esta forma:

```
  Glide.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
```

de acuerdo a tu código se realizaría de esta forma:

```
ImageView imagen = view.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
String img = tarjetaL.get(position).getImagen();
Glide.with(context).load(img).into(imagen);
```

---

2)[**Picasso**](https://square.github.io/picasso/):

Agrega la siguiente dependencia a tu archivo `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
```

y ahora cargas la url en tu `ImageView` de esta forma:

```
Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
```

de acuerdo a tu código se realizaría de esta forma:

```
ImageView imagen = view.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
String img = tarjetaL.get(position).getImagen();
Picasso.get().load(img).into(imagen);
```